# Permutation on batting

Tags: permutations

Question - A baseball manager insists on having his best hitter bat fourth and pitcher bat last. In such circumstances how many batting orders are possible?

A baseball game must have 9 players with 9 specific spots and having 2 players already chosen, i come to the conclusion - 9!/2!
But the answer is still not right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do know who is the best pitcher and who the best hitter, you need not select them. Their position is already *fixed*. Remaining $7$ people can be arranged in $7$ positions in $7!$ ways.